# Full width image in background attachment not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with background image.

I have this code:

```
background-image: url('assets/images/ob5.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
```

Result/Preview:  http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/back/

(left image).

I need something like this screen: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/back/screen.jpeg

My html:

```
<section class="strona">
        <div class="container-fluid maxFluid">
            <div class="row equal">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 padding_13 padding0 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <div class="aktualnosci_film tloimgr111 ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, jak Aldus PageMakerLorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, jak Aldus PageMakerLorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, jak Aldus PageMakerLorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, jak Aldus PageMaker
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 padding_1 padding0">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding_12">
                        <div class="left22">
                            <h1 class="kontakt_nazwa">
                                Index
                            </h1>
                            <div class="kontakt_tresc"> 
                            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
                            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
                            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
                            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
                            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The left image is visible in full width.

Background-attachment effect: fixed I would like to keep.

How to fix it?

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '*background-size: cover*' CSS property will cover the entire width of the background even if it has to stretch or crop the image. Try to control the width of the background-size using percentages.

```
.tloimgr111 {
    background-image: url('assets/images/ob5.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Note the height of the element is 100vh, forcing the element to the full view height

**Edit**


To move the image to the right you will need to restructure your HTML to look like the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9 padding_1 padding0">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding_12">
        <div class="left22">
            <h1 class="kontakt_nazwa">
                Index
            </h1>
           <div class="kontakt_tresc"> 
               Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jakprzykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 padding_13 padding0 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div class="aktualnosci_film tloimgr111 ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will move the container to the right hand side of the page.


To get the image to show, you will need to position the background to the right.

```
.tloimgr111 {
    background-image: url('assets/images/ob5.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's much better now, but the picture is too stretched. I would like to get the effect like this: https: // bit.ly/2yFbvVt

Comment: If you want the image to fill the entire width of your container it will be stretched as the width of the container is larger than the width of the image. 
If you want the image to preserve its aspect ratio, change the background-size property to be `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Ok, it's better :) I would like to move this picture to the right (it is now left aligned). How to do it?:)

Comment: You haven't changed the structure of your HTML

Comment: No, in http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/back/ - image is in left side container - and it's okey. My problem Is with align image on left box. I want make something like "text-align:right" for this image :)

Comment: I would recommend opening another thread as that is something completely. If my post above answered your initial question, please mark it as the accepted answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
--- CSS:

```
html {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
   body{
     height: 100%;
     background-image: url("../img/doc.PNG");
      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
     margin: 0;
   }

   .main{

    min-width: 620px;
    margin-left: 425px;
   }
```

--- HTML:

```
<body>

  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="main">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
  </div>
.
.
.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a526ztgs/1/
Adjust the margin-left option in css: .main{} as you like